# how to solve scatterplot error in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, scatter

following is a part of the code I am writing,

```
for ii=1:length(k31)

B   = [k31(ii);k32(ii)];

X=abs( pinv(A)*B);

g1(ii)=X(1,:);

g2(ii)=X(2,:);

g3(ii)=X(3,:);

end

scatter(x(1:end-1), y(1:end-1), 5, g1);
```

But I am not able to plot the data, the error is as follows

```
??? Error using ==> scatter at 79

C must be a single color, a vector the same length as X, or an M-by-3 matrix.
```

x and y have the same dimensions as k31...but still it is showing such an error

Comment: What are `x` and `y`? Your problem is that either `x` and `y` are not the right length, or `k31` is not.

Comment: remove `, 5, g1` part in scatter. Check if it works firstly.

Comment: @RohanChakrabarty, what you use the other arguments for? you want variable colors for points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are feeding [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) with 4 arguments: `scatter(X, Y, S, C)`. Your error states:

> `C` must be a single color, a vector the same length as `X`, or an M-by-3 matrix.

meaning that the fourth argument `g1` does not have the same dimensions as the first argument.

What probably happened here is that you didn't re-initialize `g1` before the loop, and so it retained its previous size. Put the following line before the `for`-loop:

```
g1 = zeros(size(k31));
```

and it should work.

Comment: g1 size its 575139x1 X=3x1 x=99935x1 k31=99934x1. But I am not able to understand why g1 has such a dimensions

Comment: @RohanChakrabarty There is something wrong here. Please post the exact output to these commands: `length(k31)`, `size(X)` (inside the loop), `size(A)` (inside the loop) and `size(g1)` (inside the loop)?

Comment: xsize =3by1 Asize =2by3 g1size =575139

Comment: g1 grows as 15282....15282..15283..15283...15284..15284 and so on. while  length(k31) gives 99934

Comment: @RohanChakrabarty Ok. I think that you just didn't initialize `g1` correctly. Please put the line `g1 = zeros(size(k))` **before ** the loop, and use `scatter` like normally you used in the question.